# How to send pictures from back-end to the front-end in ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fs

I am working with ReactJS, and I need to serve some pictures in my front end, I can't do it in the following way  `<img alt="" src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + image + ".png" } />` because I will serve more than 2 pictures starting with a specific keyword, so I am thinking to do like this

```
      dir= '../../public/images/'
      files= fs.readdirSync(dir)

      for (const file of files) {
        if(file.startsWith(keyword))
        {
           setPictureName(dir+file+ ".png")
         
        }
        }
```

But unfortunately I can't use the 'fs' module in the client side, so I am lost, should I do the processing in the back end then send those pictures ? If yet how to do it, and I would be happy to receive other suggestions.

Comment: You cannot and should not get data from the filesystem. Assuming you are using CreateReactApp, you need to put the files in your public folder. Then just manipulate the src to point to whichever image you want. If you want a list of all pictures, you either predefine that at the FE, or if it's dynamic, create a backend API that supplies you with this list.

Comment: @As you said, I should not get data from the filesystem. So how can I create this API ? Can you give me some example from where I can start

Comment: How will you be uploading the images to the public folder, if they are dynamic? An API is a full BackEnd application that is a lot of work, needs hosting, etc. If you are manually adding the images, just hold their names in a const array somewhere on the FE.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using express at your backend just serve the files as static from public or whatever folder you want.

```
app.use('/static', express.static('public'))
```

then get your files by calling urls like

http://localhost:3000/{your_image_name}.jpg

Comment: in my situation i have more than one picture to display and, those pictures that i want to display start with a keyword that i will specify every time , so how i can put a condition ? or how i can loop through all those pictures if i can't use the 'fs' module in the front end ?

Comment: In that case solution remains the same. You should have the name or path of the images stored in database. Just query the db as your requirements (i.e. based on your keyword prefix) and return array of image urls to frontend render it there.

Answer (score 0):

On react frontend:

```
<img src={`http://localhost:3000/images/image1.png`} alt="" />
```

I'm hoping you have already set your static folder on the node backend.. If not:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Folder structure on the backend:  public > images > image1.png